# Mounting a single file from a Docker data volume in a Docker

Tags: docker, volume, mount, single-file

I'm trying to mount a single file from a Docker volume in a container when using "docker run".

I've been able to mount an entire volume as a directory, e.g:

```
docker run -v my_volume:/root/volume my_container
```

I've also mounted single files from the physical machine, e.g:

```
docker run -v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Sure you can https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume, but I've been having the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Is there a way **always destination path/file doesn't exist in the container**, if you've created a named volume and a bind to its directory (similar to deprecated volumes_from)

```
docker run -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data/MY_FILE.txt:/destination_folder/MY_FILE.txt
```

That's why when you create a named volume and run a service/container with `docker run -v my_volume:/root/volume my_container`, data is stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data`

Comment: Is it possible to mount just single file via named volume?

Comment: @EugenKonkov, no, it's not possible. Named volume is always a directory that can contains a single file, but it cannot be a single file itself.