# Using volume for mounting a file

Tags: docker

I'm creating a volume like this:

```
docker volume create php
```

and want to mount a single file `/etc/php.ini` while running the container:

```
docker run -it -v php:/etc/php.ini image-name
```

This throws an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: readdirent: not a directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can I use volumes for this purpose or they are meant to handle directories only? What could be the solution here?

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic actually because [`docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag seems to exist for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549144/mounting-a-single-file-from-a-docker-data-volume-in-a-docker):

> when you create a named volume and run a service/container with docker run -v my_volume:/root/volume my_container, data is stored in /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data

Following this affirmation, it is unpossible to create a named volume and mount it as a file inside a container.